# Change button to selectbox code change

Tags: jquery

i have my script working but currently it used a button input, i want to change it to a select box input, but i cant seem the get the code to work at all, please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var fuel = ''; // Keep track of selections
var drive = '';
var type = '';
$('#fuel button').click(function() { // Choose a fuel
    fuel = (this.id ? '.' : '') + this.id;
    selectModels();
});
$('#drive button').click(function() { // Choose a drive
    drive = (this.id ? '.' : '') + this.id;
    selectModels();
});
$('#type button').click(function() { // Choose a colour
    type = (this.id ? '.' : '') + this.id;
    selectModels();
});
function selectModels() { // Select matching models
    $('div.modelContainer').hide(). // Hide all
        filter((fuel + drive + type) || '*').show(); // Show matches
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fuel" class="controller">
<span class="controllerLabel">fuel:</span>
<button>All</button>
<button id="petrol">petrol</button>
<button id="diesel">diesel</button>
</div>
<div id="drive" class="controller">
<span class="controllerLabel">drive:</span>
<button>All</button>
<button id="man">manual</button>
<button id="auto">auto</button>

</div>
<div id="type" class="controller">
<span class="controllerLabel">type:</span>
<button>All</button>
<button id="car">car</button>
<button id="4">4x4</button>
<button id="7">people</button>
<button id="van">van</button>

</div>



<div class="modelContainer petrol manual car">

pmc

</div>

<div class="modelContainer petrol manual 4">

pm4

</div>



<div class="modelContainer petrol auto car">

pac

</div>


<div class="modelContainer diesel manual car">

dmc

</div>



<div class="modelContainer diesel manual van">

dmv

</div>

<div class="modelContainer diesel auto car">

dac

</div>

<div class="modelContainer diesel auto 4">

da4

</div>

<div class="modelContainer diesel auto 7">

da7

</div>

<div class="modelContainer diesel auto 7 4">

sor

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And change the "fuel" buttons to

```
<div id="fuel" class="controller">
<span class="controllerLabel">fuel:</span>
<select>
<option value="all">all</option>
<option value="petrol">petrol</option>
<option value="diesel">diesel</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: The value of an `id` isn't supposed to be a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot in this question that needs to be improved upon, but this should give you immediate results:

```
$('#fuel select').on("change", function() {
    fuel = (this.value ? '.' : '') + this.value;
    selectModels();
});
```

You would need to repeat the same for the other `select` elements as well.

*Update with a few more changes:*

There are several issues with this code which could cause you some frustration in the future. I took the liberty to re-write it a bit. Granted there may still be some room for improvement, but I think it will get you a step closer to something more easily handled and understood.

I start by storing all of the filterable criteria inside a single object, rather than several variables. This gives us one place to push and pull values.

```
var fType = { 'fuel' : 'all', 'drive' : 'all', 'type' : 'all' };
```

Next I'm creating a small regular expression pattern that will find keywords within a predefined CSS selector. The function, `partsMapper`, will be responsible for swapping out the keywords that the regex discovers with the actual values from the `fType` object above.

```
var partsRegex = /([a-z]+)/g;

function partsMapper ( s, p ) {
  return fType[p];
}
```

Next, I've grouped all of your `select` elements into a single `<div class='controller'>` so that we can more easily capture their change events all from one place.

```
$(".controller").on("change", "select", function(){
```

When the change event of a `select` fires, from within `.controller`, we're start by updating the value for that change event in our `fType` object. So if `#fuel` was changed, we'll be updating `fType[fuel]` to the new value.

```
  // Set new value
  fType[ this.id ] = this.value;
```

With our `fType` object freshly updated, we can update our list of items. We start by hiding all of the list items (yeah, I restructured here as well). Next we select only the list items that match a `.fuel.drive.type` selector, where each of those keywords is found and replaced by our regular expression/function combo with the present value in the `fType` object.

So if `fType.fuel` is `"petrol"`, then our selector  will begin with `.petrol`. All of the criteria were set to `"all"` by default, so once you change `#fuel` to `petrol`, our selector will immediately become `.petrol.all.all`, which shows all `.petrol` items.

```
  // Update filtered items
  $(".modelList li")
    .hide()
  .filter('.fuel.drive.type'.replace( partsRegex, partsMapper ))
    .show();
```

Lastly we close up our `$.on` method.

```
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/imezez/edit#javascript,html

Comment: Works, thank you very much, and yes i know the code is a bit messey, thats next on my to-do list, just wanted to make it work first

Comment: @user1385301 I've provided a massive update to this answer, as well as new code and a functional demo for you. Please read at your convenience and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for being so helpfull !